# Is it possible to switch an HTML feature (falling objects) on and off with a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I currently have an HTML feature which consists of the following:

```
<marquee behavior=scroll direction=down scrollamount=2 scrolldelay=43 height=581 style='position:absolute; left:17%; top:23px; width:100; height:581px;'><font></font></marquee>
```

repeated several times. I was wondering if it's possible to include a button which turns this feature on and off, and how I'd go about doing it?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee - "While some browsers still support it, it's not required. In addition, using this element is basically one of the worst things you can do to your users, so please, please don't do it." ~MDN

Comment: you can set display:none or display:block

Comment: That obsolete message is one of the best

Comment: @day I'm aware of this, however I want it for a specific purpose. The question was "is it possible?", not "what's your opinion on it?". Also, that's the exact reason I'm looking to make a button; for users to be able to switch it on only if they please.